# Updating a certain column and line on a CSV file

Tags: c

My friend and I are working on a simple (turns out it is not as simple as it sounded to us at first) ATM project, which, we thought, was suitable for beginners like us. This console application would let users to register an account, then log in to do other withdraw/deposit stuff. We could successfully write customer info on a CSV file, then parse it to do an ID and password check and let users in to use other functions.

What we could not figure out is how to update a certain string. Say, the user with ID 64 logged in and wants to withdraw money. Then the program has to find that customers line on CSV and update the corresponding column (say column 5) to subtract some amount of money.

We tried implementing `fseek` and `fscanf` with no success. What function should we look into?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int loginState = 0, line=0; /*Kept the line variable as a global one so I can set the cursor to desired line if needed */

struct Customers customer;
struct Customers{
    int id;
    char fname[20];
    char lname[20];
    int password;
    int cashAmount;
};

void registerAccount(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    customer.id = rand()%99999;

    FILE *cstm = fopen("customers.csv", "a+");

    printf("An ID is set automatically for you.\n");
    printf("Please enter your first name.\n");
    scanf("%s", customer.fname);
    printf("Please enter your last name.\n");
    scanf("%s", customer.lname);
    printf("Please set a password.\n");
    scanf("%d", &customer.password);
    customer.cashAmount = 0;

    fprintf(cstm, "%d,%s,%s,%d,%d\n", customer.id, customer.fname, customer.lname, customer.password, customer.cashAmount);
    fclose(cstm);
}

int parser(int idSearch, int passwordCheck){ /*Takes input from login() function and does an ID and password check*/
    char lineBuffer[255];

    FILE *cstm = fopen("customers.csv", "r");

    while(fgets(lineBuffer,sizeof(lineBuffer),cstm))
    {
        ++line;
        char* id = strtok(lineBuffer, ",");
        if (atoi(id) == idSearch){
            customer.id = atoi(id);

            char* fname = strtok(NULL, ",");
            if (fname != NULL){
                strcpy(customer.fname, fname);
            }

            char* lname = strtok(NULL, ",");
            if (lname != NULL){
                strcpy(customer.lname, lname);
            } 

            char* password=strtok(NULL, ",");
            if (password != NULL){
                if(atoi(password) == passwordCheck){
                    customer.password = atoi(password);
                    loginState = 1;
                }
                else{
                    printf("You have entered the wrong password.\n");
                }
            }       

            char* cashAmount=strtok(NULL, "\n");
            if (cashAmount != NULL){
                customer.cashAmount = atoi(cashAmount);
            }
            fclose(cstm);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    printf("Could not find the ID.\n");
    fclose(cstm);
}

int login(){
    int passwordCheck, idSearch;

    printf("Please put your ID in.\n");
    scanf("%d", &idSearch);
    printf("Please put your password.\n");
    scanf("%d", &passwordCheck);

    if(parser(idSearch, passwordCheck) == 1){
        return 1;
    }
}

void balanceOperations(int option){
    int amount;
    FILE *cstm = fopen("customers.csv", "a+");

    if(option == 1){
        printf("\nYour current balance is: %d dollars.\n", customer.cashAmount);
        printf("How much would you like to deposit?\n");
        scanf("%d", &amount);
        customer.cashAmount = customer.cashAmount + amount;
        /* update function comes here */
        printf("Your new balance is %d dollars.\n", customer.cashAmount);
    }

    else if(option == 2){
        printf("\nYour current balance is: %d dollars.\n", customer.cashAmount);
        printf("How much would you like to withdraw?\n");
        scanf("%d", &amount);
        customer.cashAmount = customer.cashAmount - amount;
        printf("Your new balance is %d dollars.\n", customer.cashAmount);
    }

    else{
        printf("Something went wrong. Terminating in 5 seconds...\n");
        sleep(5);
        exit(0);
    }
}

void transaction(){

}

void loginChoices(){
    int answer;

    printf("Please select an operation.");

    while(1){
    printf("\n1. Deposit\n2. Withdraw\n3. Transaction\n");
    scanf("%d", &answer);
    switch(answer){
        case 1:
            balanceOperations(answer);
            break;
        case 2:
            balanceOperations(answer);
            break;
        case 3:
            transaction(answer);
            break;
        default:
            printf("\nInvalid request. Please enter a valid option.\n");
    }
}
}

int main(){

    int answer;

    printf("\nWelcome.\nPlease enter the digit of corresponding operation.\n");
    printf("1. Login.\n2. Register.\n");
    scanf("%d",&answer);

    if(answer == 1){
        if(login() == 1 && loginState == 1){
            printf("\nYou have logged in successfully.\n");
            printf("Your current balance is: %d dollars.\n\n", customer.cashAmount);
            loginChoices();
        }
    }

    else if(answer == 2){
        registerAccount();
    }

    else{
        printf("Please enter a valid number.\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the update changes the length of the data, you have a problem.  If you write fixed size records to the file, this isn't a problem, but using `printf()` is.  To update a file with a different size of entry, by far the simplest (and usually most effective) technique is to make a copy of the file with the entry (or entries) edited when appropriate.  Old-style mainframe batch processing took this to extremes, but usually used fixed-size records even so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you have poorly designed your program by maintaining global variables for current customer and line number of current customer in file.

---

Anyway not much editing to your current code, you can do as below.

Find my explanation in code comments.

```
void balanceOperations(int option){
    int amount;
    FILE *cstm = fopen("customers.csv", "r+"); //Open file for update, not a+

    FILE *tempFile = fopen("temp.csv", "w+");

    char lineBuffer[255];
    int temp = line-1;  //Your global variable which maintains the line number


    /*Loop till you get the current customer from the file*/
    while(fgets(lineBuffer,sizeof(lineBuffer),cstm))
    {
            if(option == 1){

                if (!temp)
                {
                   printf("\nYour current balance is: %d dollars.\n", customer.cashAmount);
                   printf("How much would you like to deposit?\n");
                   scanf("%d", &amount);

                   customer.cashAmount = customer.cashAmount + amount;

                   /*Overwrite the correct amount*/
                   fprintf(tempFile, "%d,%s,%s,%d,%d\n", customer.id, customer.fname, customer.lname, customer.password, customer.cashAmount);
                   printf("Your new balance is %d dollars.\n", customer.cashAmount);


                }
                else
                {
                     fputs(lineBuffer, tempFile);
                }
            }
            else if(option == 2){
                printf("\nYour current balance is: %d dollars.\n", customer.cashAmount);
                printf("How much would you like to withdraw?\n");
                scanf("%d", &amount);
                if (!temp)
                {
                   customer.cashAmount = customer.cashAmount - amount;

                   /*Overwrite the correct amount*/
                   fprintf(tempFile, "%d,%s,%s,%d,%d\n", customer.id, customer.fname, customer.lname, customer.password, customer.cashAmount);
                   printf("Your new balance is %d dollars.\n", customer.cashAmount);
                }
                else
                {
                     fputs(lineBuffer, tempFile);
                }
            }
            else{
                printf("Invalid operation. Terminating in 5 seconds...\n");
                exit(5);
            }
            temp--;
      }
      fclose(cstm);
      fclose(tempFile);
      remove("customers.csv");
      rename ("temp.csv","customers.csv");
 }
```

Comment: Yes, but it does add a new line which does not really solve the issue. I was trying to update the line, not add a new one while keeping the old one.

Comment: @ÖzençB. No it does not add new line I have tried it.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to update "a+" mode to "r". It does work now but for only the first line of csv file. It won't do anything for the rest.

Comment: @ÖzençB. it works for all the lines, just replace the complete code and try.

Comment: I have, and it won't update other customers unfortunately. I am uploading the current version here: [code](https://pastebin.com/m8JuyBCt)

Comment: @ÖzençB. It can't be done this way, You better created temporary file and copy the contents to new file.